# ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4550 Graphic Card desktop equivalent?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, ati-mobility-radeon

Game's and program's system requirements are always based on desktop versions and therefore laptop users are somewhat left behind since the laptop version (ATI `Mobility` branch, for e.g.) perform worse than the desktop counterpart.

**So the question:**

What is the nearest match for the desktop version of "ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4550" graphic card (512MB RAM)? On a wider question, how you actually meter your laptop card to find a desktop equivalent?

---

*Extra info:*

According to [NotebookCheck.net](http://www.notebookcheck.net/ATI-Mobility-Radeon-HD-4550.25536.0.html):

> Compared to the **desktop ATI Radeon HD 4550**, the **mobile 4550** features a *slower core clock* (600 versus 500) but can *have a higher memory clock*. Therefore, the performance should be more or less comparable (the mobile card will be a bit slower).

Says one thing is worse, other is better but in the end, worse than the desktop counterpart. So the true equivalent would be a 3XXX series or what?

I've read on Wikipedia about the [Radeon Nomenclature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon#Nomenclature), which the first number is the chipset and the second performance. But I've seen people saying that `5850` is better than `8800GT` so I'm really confused. Shouldn't newer chipset, with same performance be better?

Comment: The 8800GT is Nvidia which uses a different naming scheme.

Comment: 4550 series graphic card performs as a 4500 series graphic card.  Your question makes no sense, even your quote, says it will perform about the same.

Comment: @Ramhound 'a bit slower' is not 'equal' thus I can't use the desktop 4550 as "equivalent" IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "mobility" series cards are lower clocked in order to reduce power consumption, so performance will be *slightly* degraded compared to the desktop counterpart.

By slightly, I mean probably not very noticeable especially if you overclock the card yourself to the desktop's specs.

The easiest way to compare is to run [3DMark](http://www.3dmark.com/) on both chips and see which fares better.

Comment: Got any reliable source on how overclock it?

Comment: Could try this: http://www.techpowerup.com/atitool/ - your mileage may vary. Don't overclock unless you know what you're doing. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I just wanna test FFXIV benchmark with overclocked to see if it gets a better score. That's why I made the question. Says minimum Radeon 4770 HD but mine is a 4550 that isn't much like a 4550 because of mobility